# MaxResults returns Invalid integer value for Calendar API

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-calendar-api

I currently use a get Request in a Google Chrome App to pull events of my Calendar (API v3). Everything works fine, but when I use maxResults to limit the output, I get

```
"message": "Invalid integer value: '20?
```

The code is:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?maxResults=20?access_token="+token, true);
xhr.send();
```

Why isn't this recognized as an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this was obvious: I missed a question mark (only first parameter uses a question mark, all others following use &). So instead of

```
xhr.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?maxResults=20?access_token="+token, true)
```

it should have been

xhr.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?maxResults=20&access_token="+token, true)